# How to do a shadowed border on a form input?

Tags: html, css, psd

Hello I am tasked to make an input field look like the screenshot below:

[image]

I can do everything except the border shadow thing. Is this possible using css?

In the photoshop file, this layer is given an "Inner Glow" and this is responsible for the border shadow.

Here is a screenshot of the layer style:

[image]

Here is my css so far just incase it is needed:

```
#input_1_1 {
    background-color: #f1f5f6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    height: 47px;
    padding: 0 17px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `box-shadow`–just play around with the values until you match the mockup.

```
input {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir this is a great starting point i will mess around with the values

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```css
#input_1_1 {
    background-color: #f1f5f6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    height: 47px;
    padding: 0 17px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<input id="input_1_1" type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: thanks! bezierer beat you by a few minutes but i gave you an upvote